# Kendo DataSource requestEnd event gets fired multiple times

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC and i have grid defined as below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(o => o.ID)
                .ClientTemplate("<input class = 't-checkbox-selectrow' type='checkbox' value='#=ID#'/><label></label>")
                .HeaderTemplate("<input class = 't-checkbox-selectallrows' type='checkbox' id='selectAll'/><label></label>")
                .Sortable(false)
                .Filterable(false)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "t-gridcol-selectrow" })
                .Width(40)
                .Locked(true).Lockable(false);            
            col.Bound(o => o.StatusName).Width(150);
            col.Bound(o => o.Deadline).Width(120);
            col.Bound(o => o.Cost).Width(150);                        
        })        
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(UIConstants.PageSizes))
        .Sortable(x => x.AllowUnsort(false))
        .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Scrollable(s => s.Height("Auto"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(UIConstants.DefaultPageSizeMax)
            .Read(read => read
            .Action("GetData", "DataProvider"))
            .ServerOperation(false))
    )
```

Then in the JS file i am resetting the grid's page to 1 onRequestEnd, So user always goes back to first page whenever i fetch the data from remote service

```
 $(function(){
     var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
     ds.bind("requestEnd", function (e){      
       e.sender.page(1);
     })
    })
```

As per the [kendo's documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd)

> requestEnd
>   Fired when a remote service request is finished.

However the `requestEnd` event also gets fire on page change (and sorting). So when i change the page programmatic it fires the `requestEnd` event again and goes into loop. *( note `requestEnd` also gets fired when i change Page or Sort manually on UI)*

Is this is by design or wrong documentation?

Comment: I have struggled myself with this question for a while and I haven't found an answer since the kendo Grid doesn't appear to have an event that fires only on first load and I have looked quite a lot. Most cases that I had this problem I reseted the page as soon as I refetched my data. Either on button click either on demand.

Answer (score 1):

i did something like below. `e.response` will be only populated when `requestEnds` as part of response from server. In all other cases it will null.

```
dataSource.bind("requestEnd", function (e) {
        if (e.status != "error" && e.response != null) {                             
               // do soemething here                
        }
```

I would really like kendo team either fix the issue or create new event

Comment: Upvoted because this solution works for what I was trying to achieve through: `dataSource.options.requestEnd = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked 3 years ago, but I am coming across it while looking up some other information. While I am here, I will answer it for others, as LP13 is likely not concerned about this anymore.

In the HTML Razer code, add the **RequestEnd** event to the DataSource. Here is an example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    // (snip)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(o => o.DataBound("onDataBound"))
        .PageSize(UIConstants.DefaultPageSizeMax)
        .Read(read => read
        .Action("GetData", "DataProvider"))
        .ServerOperation(false))
)
```

Now in your jquery, you would write your event handler:

```js
function onRequestEnd(e) {
    console.log('onRequestEnd: e.response Object(The raw remote service response) = ', e.response);
    console.log('onRequestEnd: e.sender kendo.data.DataSource(The data source instance which fired the event) = ', e.sender);
    console.log('onRequestEnd: e.type String (The type of the request) = ', e.type);
}
```

Comment: Reference: https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-you-bind-a-custom-function-to-the-requestend-event-of-a-datasource-with-mvc-notation-